# Save List of Links from Array to Text File (almost got it working)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops

I'm trying to save all the link strings into a text document, but it only saves the last link in the document (in this case Youtube.com).

I want it to save all the links to the saved txt document, what am I doing wrong?

https://jsfiddle.net/zfL2hzvp/4/

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');

// Loop through all links
 for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {

// Store links in variable
var linksArray = links[i];

// Works fine in console
   console.log(linksArray);
 }


 // Create text document — only saves 1st link in text doc
 var textDoc = document.createElement('a');

 textDoc.href = 'data:attachment/text,' + encodeURI(linksArray);
 textDoc.target = '_blank';
 textDoc.download = 'myFile.txt';
 textDoc.click();
```

Can someone help me out here? 
Thank you! :-)

Comment: Your code overwrites the value of `linksArray` on each iteration. That's what an `=` assignment does: replace the former value of a variable with a new value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(function() {


  var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');

  var linksArray = [];
  // Loop through all links
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {

    // Store links in variable
    linksArray.push(links[i]);

    // Works fine in console
    console.log(linksArray);
  }


  // Create text document — only saves 1st link in text doc
  var textDoc = document.createElement('a');

  textDoc.href = 'data:attachment/text,' + encodeURI(linksArray.join('\n'));
  textDoc.target = '_blank';
  textDoc.download = 'myFile.txt';
  textDoc.click();

  })();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/um4qhsks/1/

Comment: Your fiddle does not work; the OP wants to be able to download the data URL the code is supposed to build.

Comment: @Pointy check code inside answer  -- there is some but with forking

Comment: ?? I don't know what that means.

Comment: Update link for fiddle -- code in answer is correct. Incorrect was only link to fiddle

Comment: But it still does not work. I get no download dialog. *edit* OK it works in Chrome but not Firefox, which may be insurmountable.

Comment: It works fine in Chrome. If at your browser it doesn't -- give more details ( also I didn't change any download logic )

Comment: Thank you Vasiliy Vanchuk, it works exactly like I wanted, I can see what I did wrong too, still got a lot to learn :-)

Comment: It's true that it doesn't work in FireFox and also not Safari. I don't need it to, but out of curiosity it would be nice to know why. Maybe they have some built-in protection against auto-download scripts?  It works fine in Opera btw.